# execute setup.exe to install the software on remote machine

Tags: powershell-4.0

I'm trying to run `installer.exe` on a remote server using a powershell script.
I have used `Copy-Item` to copy the installer in the remote machine.
I have also tried `Invoke-command -computername $Server`, but nothing works.

After reading few posts on Stackoverflow i have also used `winrm` to make the server in the list of trusted hosts, but again nothing works for me.

Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

I have tried this as well to check if things really work on my remote machine:

```
Invoke-Command - Computername abc -ScriptBlock{Start-process calc.exe}
```

Answer (score 0):

On remote computer you need to configure WinRM to accept connections

```
winrm quickconfig
```

On local computer edit WSMan trusted list (usually to trust all)

```
Set-Item -force WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts  –Value *
```

Now you should be able to execute  remote command

```
$command = [scriptblock]::create("get-service")
$Result = invoke-command -ComputerName $servername -ScriptBlock $command
```

Based on whether or not the target computer is in the same domain, and if you have admin rights, you may also need to include credentials in your *Invoke-command* statement.

```
$Result = invoke-command -ComputerName $servername -ScriptBlock $command -Cred $AdminCred
```